# Save data from multiple classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

I have looked around a lot and I have looked into many comparable questions and types of guis but unfortunately I am still not able to solve my problem. Currently I am working on an Tkinter gui with multiple pages. People have to insert certain properties and eventually i would like to print those properties on the last page. Therefore i have to acces the entry values from different classes. However, somehow i'm not able to this. Could somebody help me with this?

```
import tkinter as tk
class Main(tk.Tk):

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)




        container = tk.Frame(self)


        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)


            self.frames[F] = frame
            self.geometry("700x400")
            self.wm_title('Size')
            self["bg"]="white"

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")



        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()        


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()        


import tkinter as tk

class StartPage(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller 
        self["bg"]="white"

        label1=tk.Label(self, text="What are the sizes?",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 10")
        label1.pack()
        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Length :",fg="green",font="verdana 8",bg="white")
        L1.pack()
        L1.place(x=220,y = 50)

        self.E1 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
        self.E1.pack()
        self.E1.place(x=370,y=50)



        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next",width=25,height=2, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button.place(x=470,y = 180)
        button.config(bg="green",fg='white')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self["bg"]="white"

        page1 = self.controller.get_page(StartPage) 
        var = page1.E1.get()
        label1=tk.Label(self, text="You have insert",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 10")
        label1.pack()
        label2=tk.Label(self, text=var,bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 10")
        label2.pack()





app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: didn't you ask this before? What did you try to do? What did you get? Did you get error message ? Always put full Traceback in question as text.

Comment: every page has access to `parent` and `controller` do you can use it to store data in `parent` or `controller` -ie. `self.controller.data1 = "some data"`. Or you can ise it to access other pages ie. `self.controller.frames[StartPage].E1.get()`

Comment: `place()`, `pack()` and `grid()` are three layour managers - don't mix it. If you use `place()` then don't need `pack()`. If you use `pack()` then don't need `place()`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because `PageOne.__init__` is executed at start, before you even see `StartPage`, so `Entry` is still empty when you use `var = page1.E1.get()`

You can add method `update_page()` to every page and execute it when you change page (when you click button). This way `update_page` can use `var = page1.E1.get()` to get value after you put text in `Entry`

I added Button `"Back"` so you can go back to `StartPage` and change value in `Entry` and when you go to `PageOne` you see new value.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("700x400")

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()        
        frame.update_page() # <-- update data on page when you click button

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller 

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="What are the sizes?")
        label1.pack()

        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Length :")
        L1.pack()

        self.E1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.E1.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

    def update_page(self): # empty method but I need it
        pass   

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="You have insert")
        label1.pack()

        # create empty label at start
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.label2.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

    def update_page(self):
        # update label when page is changed
        page1 = self.controller.get_page(StartPage) 
        var = page1.E1.get()
        self.label2['text'] = var


app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. It helped a lot!